# Use Semantic UI with Lerna and yarn workspaces

Tags: semantic-ui, yarnpkg, lerna, yarn-workspaces

The Semantic UI (and Fomantic UI) installer (famously?) doesn't support yarn because of its interactive postinstall script. Even with `"autoInstall": true` in `semantic.json`, yarn will still break on the first install.

This makes it hard to keep a themed Semantic UI installation in its own package in a Lerna monorepo, when using workspaces. Even if `--ignore-scripts` is added to Lerna's `package.json` scripts, it will still run a standard `yarn install` by itself every now and then when making changes, and become blocked by Semantic UI.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to edit `packages/semantic-ui/package.json`, removing `"semantic-ui"` from `dependencies` and adding the script `"install": "node ./install.js"`. Then create a script that spawns `npm install semantic-ui --no-save`, only if yarn is detected in the environment (to prevent an infinite install loop; check `process.env.npm_config_user_agent`).

This is a convoluted and error-prone way, however if a `semantic.json` with `"autoInstall": true` is present it will automatically install Semantic UI and run the gulp job, making the custom theme available to other packages at `@monorepo/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css`.

Answer (score 1):

You can in fact get the `autoInstall` to work with yarn using fomantic-ui, I just ran these commands and it worked

```
$ yarn add fomantic-ui --ignore-scripts
$ yarn --cwd node_modules/fomantic-ui run install
```

semantic.json

```
-  "autoInstall": false,
+  "autoInstall": true,
```

Now every time `yarn install` is ran it will "skip" the install script.

> Make sure you are using the latest version of FUI

There is also a whole issue about this problem on the FUI repo https://github.com/fomantic/Fomantic-UI/issues/386

Comment: Although autoInstall + ignore-scripts lets you use yarn in a stand-alone project, it is not enough when you have Lerna/workspaces which does automatic yarn stuff. Like, I could do `lerna bootstrap --ignore-scripts` but subsequent `lerna add` would still break on this. I think the SUI/FUI repo issues were a bit too quick to accept this "solution". :-)